# Custom action cannot access registry key for read

Tags: wix

I have a custom action which reads registry entry. If the `session["UtillRegKey"]` already have on registry, `printerIndex` should increment. 
The problem is even the registry already have, `prnKey` always become null. I don't think for reading registry is not required the permission, but even after sets the permission also the result was same. And then I created a windows form application, and add the same function there, and it works as I expected.

Can anyone explain why this `prnKey = prnKey.OpenSubKey(registryPath, false);` gives null with WIX custom action. and how can i overcome this problem.

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult RegistryDetails(Session session)
{
    try
    {
        string registryPath = session["UtillRegKey"];
        int printerIndex = 1;
        RegistryKey prnKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
        prnKey = prnKey.OpenSubKey(registryPath, false);

        if (null != prnKey)
        {
            global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Not NUll");
            List<string> subKeyList = new List<string>();
            subKeyList.AddRange(prnKey.GetSubKeyNames());

            while (subKeyList.Contains(printerIndex.ToString()))
            {
                printerIndex++;
            }
        }

        string newRegistryPath = registryPath + "\\" + printerIndex.ToString();
        session["UtillRegKey"] = newRegistryPath;
        session["PrinterNo"] = printerIndex.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        CurrentSession.Log(ex.Message);
        Record exceptionRec = new Record(0);
        exceptionRec[0] = "Errors -" + ex.StackTrace.ToString();
        CurrentSession.Message(InstallMessage.Error, exceptionRec);

        return ActionResult.Failure;
    }
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is not a Key then `prnKey = null` so, if it is not a permision problem, then it should that key is not available there. What you shoul aware of build with x86 and run it on a x64 may gives you some trouble. Because the path is not same. either you have to build for correct configuration or Try explicit open

```
RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
```